# to plot points on a country map dynamically

Tags: python, google-maps, dictionary, google-earth, matplotlib-basemap

I am working on a taxi dataset. I want to plot them on country map.
also, after plotting the trajectories of the taxis, i want the user to choose a point on the map and request him to enter an epsilon radius. After he enters a value, a circle should be drawn for the user-selected point and points of other taxis within that circle should be engulfed. I should show the user how many taxis are participating in that epsilon radius.
       so what sorta APIs or packages should i use? Does basemap in python provide with this kind of dynamism. Or is there any other tool i can use?
Or is there a way, where there are ready maps available and i can just plot my trajectories on them and include them in my web-based GUI and provide the user to enter epsilon radius and do the same stuff as i mentioned above. how to go ahead? please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This might be more easily accomplished using the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) and JavaScript on the client side. Your server-side component sending the coordinates of taxis could certainly be done in Python using [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com), or whichever framework you choose, but for ease of mapping and dynamic data generation in the browser JavaScript/HTML5 is the way to go.